# Filter number of polygon inside polygon in Geoqueryset Django

Tags: django, gis, polygon, postgis, geodjango

I have 2 Models "Building" and "Flood", both are in srid 32651 My purpose are want to calculate how many building get hits by flood, I use :

```
affected = Building.objects.filter(geom__within=Flood.geom)
```

but somehow I get "object with type SpatialProxy for a spatial lookup parameter"

Is there something wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your query against a `Flood` model instance and not against the class itself.

```
flood = Flood.objects.first() # That gives you the first object of type Flood found in the DB
affected = Building.objects.filter(geom__within=flood.geom)
```